# NSAlert not working with NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I have an NSAlert with a NSView accessory view that contains two NSTextField's. I can put the cursor in the NSTextField's but I cannot type in them. Instead, it will type in the last line I was typing on in Xcode. I am using Xcode 6.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSAlert *passRequest = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [passRequest setMessageText:@"Finder wants to restart. Type your       password to allow this."];
    [passRequest addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [passRequest addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [passRequest setAccessoryView:[InputView inputViewWithUsername:@"James Pickering"]];

    NSImage *lockImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"LOCK_YOSEMITE.png"];
    [passRequest setIcon:lockImage];
    [passRequest runModal];
}
```

I did implement the LSUIElement key, but even before that it wasn't running properly. Otherwise, it's straight out of the box cocoa app.

Here is my code for InputView:

```
#import "InputView.h"

@interface InputView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *username;

@end

@implementation InputView

+ (InputView *)inputViewWithUsername:(NSString *)username {
    InputView *view = [[self alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 52))];
    [view setUsername:username];
    return view;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSTextField *usernameLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 32, 71, 17))];

    [usernameLabel setStringValue:@"Username:"];
    [[usernameLabel cell] setBordered:NO];
    [[usernameLabel cell] setBezeled:NO];

    [usernameLabel setEditable:NO];
    [usernameLabel setSelectable:NO];
    [usernameLabel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [usernameLabel setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [self addSubview:usernameLabel];

    NSTextField *passwordLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(2, 2, 69, 17))];

    [passwordLabel setStringValue:@"Password:"];
    [[passwordLabel cell] setBordered:NO];
    [[passwordLabel cell] setBezeled:NO];

    [passwordLabel setEditable:NO];
    [passwordLabel setSelectable:NO];
    [passwordLabel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [passwordLabel setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [self addSubview:passwordLabel];

    NSTextField *usernameInput = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(77, 30, 206, 22))];

    [usernameInput setStringValue:self.username];
    [usernameInput setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [self addSubview:usernameInput];

    NSTextField *passwordInput = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(77, 0, 206, 22))];

    [passwordInput setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [self addSubview:passwordInput];
}

@end
```

Comment: void displayFinderAlertWithMessage(NSString *msg) ?  You'd better be better than that.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I am calling this function in int main.

This is your problem. An alert needs a full application set up and running its event loop. In order for typing to go to it, it will need to be the active application.

You should probably create a normal app from Xcode's template. Start with that. Get things working there. You can present your alert in an action method that's connected to a menu item or a button in a window or whatever. (You could also present in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` app delegate method, I suppose.)

After you've got that working, if there's some reason you need this to work in an unusual context (e.g. command-line tool), you can work on that.

---

You are modifying the view hierarchy inside of your `-drawRect:` method. You must not do this.

First, `-drawRect:` may be called many times over the life of the view and you would be adding subviews ***every time it draws***. More and more subviews, over and over.

Second, even if you were careful to only add them the first time, `-drawRect:` is for drawing and not for changing the view hierarchy. (There's `-viewWillDraw` if you need to make such changes just before drawing, but I don't think that's appropriate for this case, either.)

You can add the subviews in an override of `-initWithFrame:` instead.

By the way, you should probably use `NSMakeRect()` instead of `NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(...))`.

Comment: So I added the code to the app delegate, but I still have the same problem. This time, I get the spinning beachball when I do anything with it.

Comment: This is a normal, complete bundled app? And it's being launched in the normal way (from Xcode, the Finder, or the Dock)? Update your question to show the new code. Are you sure that Xcode hasn't stopped the process because it hit an exception, signal, or breakpoint? You can use Activity Monitor to sample the process when it's stuck. Put that sample report into your question, too.

Comment: At this point, I would guess the hang or whatever is happening in your `InputView` class. A sample report would help indicate that, as would the code of that class.